# Gravitational potential in a system of two particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, potential-energy

Suppose two particles with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ are interacting via a central force. Lets work in the center-of-mass frame, and let $r$ be the distance from the masses to the center of mass which lies at the origin. The distance between the masses is now $2r$. The potential of the first mass $m_1$ is the amount of negative work done needed to bring $m_1$ to a distance of $2r$ from $m_2$ all the way from infinity. That is
$$U_1 = - \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{m_1 m_2k}{\bar{\vert r\vert}}\bigg).$$

The potential of $m_2$ is by the exact same arguments
$$U_2 = - \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{m_1 m_2k}{\bar{\vert r\vert}}\bigg).$$

where $\bar{r}$ is the position vector of the center of mass, and $k$ is a constant. On the other hand, the total potential energy of this system is the amount of negative work needed in order to bring an object from infinity to the center of mass. So the total potential is the quantity written in parenthesis. Therefore
$$U_1 + U_2=\frac{1}{2}U_{tot}+\frac{1}{2}U_{tot}=U_{tot}.$$

Is this reasoning valid?

Comment: If $m_1\ne m_2$ your $r$ and $2r$ distances don't make sense. The larger mass must be closer to your origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Potential of one is this and the other is this** is a misnomer at best. The potential energy is stored in the fields and is simply given by-

$$U=-\dfrac{Gm_1m_2}{r}$$

where $r$ is the distance between them.

There is no meaning to the potential of mass $m_1$. Potential of this system at a point would be equal to the work required to bring a test mass to that point.

I hope you can work out the details. If not let me know in the comments.

Comment: Suppose we look at the total energies of both particles individually. Then for a particle 1, E1 = K1 + U1 right? Moreover the energy of the system is E1 + E2 = K1 + K2 + ( ? ) certainly we wont have U1 + U2 here now right, nor 2U? Rather the sum of the potentials in this calculus should add up to the total potential of the system? In other words, each particle should contribute half of the total potential energy, correct?

Comment: Sarthak: Your formula is right, but it's an interesting philosophical question to wonder where the potential energy is stored.  If it's in the field, then from E=mc^2 the field should have some mass, but where is this mass?  Are extra particles created, or is it stored in various proportions in the two original masses?

Comment: @variations **Each particle contributes to half of the potential energy**-- This statement is again missing the point. Each particle doesn't have a significance without the other particle. When you want to find the energy of this system, you write it is $E=K_1+K_2+U$.  Each particle contributing to half of the potential energy would acquire a meaning if removing one particle halves the PE. It doesnt. It makes PE of the system 0, since there are no interactions.

Comment: @John Hunter --- Yes gravitational field does carry mass but in general relativity energy amd mass are the same things. You look at energy and you realise this must have some mass.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two equal masses, each at a distance of , r, from the center of mass, and you move them one at a time out to infinity, then the work to move the first one will be W = Gmm/(2r), but the work to move the second one will be zero, since there is no longer a force on it from the other mass. The initial total potential energy was -Gmm/(2r).